# Upload Documents using Selenium in Windows pop up

Tags: c#, windows, selenium

I’m trying to upload documents in Selenium using C# on windows bas pop up using Sendkeys.Sendwait(filepath) however I have connected to RDC once it get locked automatically SendKeys.Sendwait won’t work ..is there any alternative I can use to upload file on Windows using Selenium

Selenium using C# up loading documents on Windows pop upI cannot use Xpath/ID

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use WindowsForms to be able to sendkeys to the upload window. If you have a console app, this approach may not work for you. It essentially looks something like this :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//This button click opens the Windows Upload Window
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("UploadButton")).Click();

//The thread sleep is to account for the upload window opening
Thread.Sleep(2000);

//In the SendKeys, we send the full path to what we want to upload, as well as {RIGHT} 
//which represents clicking right on the key board which will move the focused option in 
//the window to the "Enter" option
SendKeys.SendWait(GetProjectRoot() + @"\DataFiles\red.png" + @"{RIGHT}");

//This Send Keys presses the enter key, submitting the path we inputted for upload
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");

//Accounts for the upload + window closing
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

The only downside to this is that if you click somewhere else on windows when it comes to send the path, it will send the path on whichever other window you clicked.